# Can you reliably implement E2EE for web applications without a seperate client installed application or server?

Tags: encryption

E2EE (End to end encryption), for it to be complete means the server has no knowledge of the keys the client uses to encrypt their data. As such, keys have to be stored client side, however this poses certain questions I am unable to wrap my head around:

1. How could the user store the keys safely?

   - The only thing I can think of is they own their own server, which is basically a key provider for them.
2. I have read some E2EE providers first have the user enter a password, which is then hashed and this is what then encrypts their data before sending it to the server. But then I ask - how would a user reset their password?

Comment: About your questions: 1. What kind of keys are we talking about here (secret, public, private)? LocalStorage seems fine enough. Everything else is probably just some obfuscation when we don't have a HSM in the browser.  2. What do you understand as end-to-end? What are the ends you're talking about? If a user uses a password and encrypt data based on that password, they have to be their own receiver, because they generally should give away their password to some other recipient.

Comment: 1. Private key. If local storage is used then how do you use the app across devices? 2. E2ee means only the receivers can decrypt. So maybe you have private photos then only you have the key to decrypt and view them. Whereas private messaging would mean some form of shared public keys with the two people messaging BUT importantly the server must never receive these keys. Maybe they are sent out of band but again this isn't user friendly hence my confusion

Comment: I read a white paper from corporateencryption.com which just ended up giving me more wtfs

Comment: https://corporateencryption.com/white-paper/

Comment: E2E encryption doesn't consider multiple sender or receiver devices. You would have a different key per device. Anyway, your question *"Can you reliably implement E2EE for web applications without a seperate client installed application or server?"* can be be answered with *yes*, but no site on the Stack Exchange network would be appropriate to give you a complete solution to your problem, because you have to figure your constraints on your own. Perhaps you should do more reading and try to reduce the scope of the question, so that it is answerable.